# Is there a way to have VS Code 'interpret' a portion of the file with different syntax?

Tags: visual-studio-code

By 'interpret' I mean syntax highlighting, intellisense, etc.

A real-world example would be an Azure Pipelines YAML file with inline scripts:

my-template.yml

```yaml
steps:
  - bash: |
      echo "A Bash line"
      echo "Another Bash line"
    displayName: 'My Bash script.'
```

my-other-template.yml

```yaml
steps:
  - pwsh: |
      Write-Output "A Powershell Core line"
      Write-Output "Another Powershell Core line"
    displayName: 'My Powershell Core script.'
```

In these examples VS Code would be able to show different commands to type through Intellisense options and provide the appropriate syntax-highlighting for the lines pertaining to the inline scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, this is not possible natively*, but Universal Language Injection is a highly requested feature on GitHub: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/1751

You can show your interest to the VSC team by upvoting the feature request (click the thumbs up" on the first post of the thread), or you can explain your particular use-case in a comment.

*Extensions can achieve elements of this functionality.  Even if a comprehensive one for your language doesn't exist, most have GitHub pages of their own.  So if you find one with, say, just highlighting for your language, you can always raise an issue or a PR to add the rest.